# Analysing audio with Windows API in C++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, audio

(My first question here, so I hope I'm not stepping on any toes - I tried searching for my issue, but I didn't see anything that seemed to apply; but it might have and I simply didn't understand what I was looking at.)

I have never needed to work with audio before, so I'm feeling a little lost. What I need to do is simple; monitor a live feed from a microphone and when there is a spike in volume above a certain level *do stuff*. I already have the *do stuff* taken care of, but all my Google-ing to try and understand audio has just left me more confused than I started.

If it makes a difference; I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <queue>
//I figured I could put the sound info
//in a queue and push it through checking
//the volume as I went.

using namespace std;

//For this code, the below is just for debug messages
//It plays a more important role in the full code.
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
        LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);

//This seemed to be a decent way to make sure I could read in
//from the audio.
MMRESULT IsFormatSupported(LPWAVEFORMATEX pwfx, UINT uDeviceID) 
{ 
    return (waveOutOpen( 
        NULL,                 // ptr can be NULL for query 
        uDeviceID,            // the device identifier 
        pwfx,                 // defines requested format 
        NULL,                 // no callback 
        NULL,                 // no instance data 
        WAVE_FORMAT_QUERY));  // query only, do not open device 
} 

int main()
{
    UINT wReturn; 
    const int NUMPTS = 11025 * 10;   // 10 seconds
    short int waveIn[NUMPTS];
    queue<short int*> my_queue;
    WAVEFORMATEX pcmWaveFormat; 

    // Set up WAVEFORMATEX for 11 kHz 8-bit mono. 

    pcmWaveFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM; 
    pcmWaveFormat.nChannels = 1; 
    pcmWaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec = 11025L; 
    pcmWaveFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = 11025L; 
    pcmWaveFormat.nBlockAlign = 1; 
    pcmWaveFormat.wBitsPerSample = 8; 
    pcmWaveFormat.cbSize = 0;
    MMRESULT result = 0;
    HWAVEIN microHandle;
    WAVEHDR waveHeader;
    // See if format is supported by any device in system. 

    wReturn = IsFormatSupported(&pcmWaveFormat, WAVE_MAPPER); 
    // Report results. 
    if (wReturn == 0) 
    {
        //To make sure I can actually get the audio:
        //MessageBox(NULL, "11 kHz 8-bit mono IS supported.",
        //"", MB_ICONINFORMATION); 
    }
    else if (wReturn == WAVERR_BADFORMAT) 
    {
    MessageBox(NULL, "11 kHz 8-bit mono NOT supported.",
        "", MB_ICONINFORMATION); 
    return -2;
    }
    else 
    {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Error opening waveform device.",
        "Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION); 
    return -3;
    }

result = waveInOpen(&microHandle, WAVE_MAPPER,
         &pcmWaveFormat, 0L, 0L, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT); 
    // Set up and prepare header for input
    waveHeader.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn;
    waveHeader.dwBufferLength = NUMPTS*2;
    waveHeader.dwBytesRecorded=0;
    waveHeader.dwUser = 0L;
    waveHeader.dwFlags = 0L;
    waveHeader.dwLoops = 0L;
    waveInPrepareHeader(microHandle, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    // Insert a wave input buffer
    result = waveInAddBuffer(microHandle, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    waveInStart(microHandle);
    //In theory, this should stop after ten seconds,
    //as set by NUMPTS - but doesn't.
do {} while (waveInUnprepareHeader(microHandle,
    &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR))==WAVERR_STILLPLAYING);
MessageBox(NULL, "Done Recording", "", MB_ICONINFORMATION); 

    waveInClose(microHandle);

    cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
    cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    return 0;
}
```

I also had to manually go into project properties and under Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies add in Winmm.lib

I'm not certain where to go from here. I know I need to check the audio stream for volume, but I don't need to store it for use later, which is why I put the #include queue. But I don't even know what to store in the queue or how I'd read it, so I'm not entirely certain that's appropriate.

If someone has advice, answers, or a good resource for audio beginners I would appreciate it.

Comment: You need to call `waveInStart` before `waveInUnprepareHeader`

Comment: That... would probably help. Thank you.

Comment: If only SDL could do audio input as well as audio output, I'd certainly recommend it, as it's much simpler to use than any Windows API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with 16 bits/sample then the values will be near 0 for silence. A loud tone will produce a sine wave with positive and negative peaks (+32K ... - 32K).

short volume = abs(sample);

Pitch is not so easy. Technically, it is the complement of the time between zero crossings of the sine waves. There is a mathematical algorithm (FFT) to compute a pitch spectrum.

To get more familiar with these concepts get an audio editor and play with it. They display the data from waveIn or WAV files. There a bazillions of them available as shareware.

Comment: Ok, this is getting a little more complicated than I initially thought: But you've given me enough to start figuring it out, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The audio samples will be in your waveIn buffer. No need for the queue, just examine the values in waveIn.

You have used 8 bits/sample. If that's really what you want waveIn buffer is the wrong type. It should be bytes, not shorts. But 16 bits/sample is a better choice: The 8-bit data is in a funny format that will need extra conversion. If you use 16 bits per sample ordinary signed arithmetic will work for comparing the sample values.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I also need to set `pcmWaveFormat.nChannels = 2;` or it gives the "Unsupported" error. That helped with seeing the data, and I know it's working since I get different values each time when I print it out. I put `for (int x = 0; x<=15; x++){cout << waveIn[x] << endl;}` after the `waveInClose(microHandle);` and it's different each time I run it. But what do these values mean? How do I extract volume or pitch, for example? Is there a reference for this? Lastly, I'm assuming I only need to look at one piece of waveIn at a time per sound sample; is that right?